# reading bytes file offline using sockets - Java

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

I have a byte file that contains tcp packets. I want to use sockets to read those packets.

so is it possible to use Sockets to read this file without connection ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
FileInputStream mInStream = new FileInputStream("file path").
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024]; 

    // Keep listening to the InputStream 
    while (true) {
        try {
         bytes = mInStream.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
        }catch {} 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

No, but you can use a FileInputStream and read bytes from the files like the following snippet:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("path_to_file").

while((fis.read(buffer) != -1)
    // do something with the bytes readed
```